# How to authenticate in Spring Boot using Backbone and REST?

Tags: javascript, spring, rest, backbone.js, spring-boot

I am trying to wrap my head around the high level concepts and I'm just starting to learn Spring Security at the same time.  While eventually I want to support "Login via Google" (and other social media), for now I am just prototyping so all I want is a quick way to add user support to my app for testing purposes.

I am using Spring Boot and Backbone.  After the initial page load, all requests are made via REST through Backbone.  So far, I haven't done much with Spring Security, but if I add this config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .jdbcAuthentication()
            .dataSource(dataSource)             
            .usersByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, password,enabled FROM users WHERE username=?")               
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT username, authority FROM authorities WHERE username = ?")                
            .rolePrefix("ROLE_");
}
```

Then when I go to my app I get a login form and if I enter a valid user, I can access the app which is a great start.

But when Backbone tries a REST call it doesn't work.  I just get a `403 - Forbidden`.

I think I understand why this is happening at a high-level.  I assume I need to send user details with every request to the server.  But I'm not sure how that works with Spring Security and I can't find any documentation to explain it.

I would rather follow Spring Security guidelines here rather than attempt to roll my own solution and re-invent the wheel.

Is there a idiomatic way to do this in Spring Security?

Answer (score 0):

The browser should be sending session cookies with its requests, so once you have authenticated it should work fine. The fact that you have a 403 response (not a 401) suggests that it *is* working. Maybe you are asking for a resource you are not permitted to see, or maybe it's something else. If you crank up the debug logging on org.springframework.security it should tell you what's going on.

Comment: Shortly after posting my question here, I realised Spring Security logs were at 'warn' level!  My bad.  Now when I run it I get and `CsrfFilter - Invalid CSRF token found` error.  I'm now trying to figure out how to store the CSRF token in Backbone, but I haven't got it working yet.